# Is it possible to overload the nameof operator in c#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, c#-6.0

Can I overload the `nameof` operator in C#?

The [C# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators) is outdated and the [C# 6 under the hood](http://www.erikschierboom.com/2015/12/31/csharp6-under-the-hood-nameof/) doesn't help me.

How can I overload the `nameof` operator?

Comment: `nameof` is evaluated at compile time, so concept of overloading it doesn't make much sense to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nameof` operator is evaluated at compile-time.

> The nameof expression is a constant. In all cases, nameof(...) is evaluated at compile-time to produce a string. Its argument is not evaluated at runtime, and is considered unreachable code (however it does not emit an "unreachable code" warning).

So, these operator cannot be overloaded.

Comment: What are you quoting? It make sense to add reference (name, link) whenever using quote.

Comment: I don't know where @solid-fan is quoting from but here is the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators).