# Is it possible to write a wrapper for the C# nameof operator?

Tags: c#, nameof

I read a related [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811561/is-it-possible-to-overload-the-nameof-operator-in-c) about the `nameof` operator, but it didn't help me, so I asked it here.

I want to write a wrapper for the C# `nameof` operator so not only will it will return the name of a class property, but also concatenate it with the class name.

Let's assume a class with single property:

```
class Foo
{
   public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Now if compiling `Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo.SomeProperty))` with **(C# 6 or higher)**, the result will be:

> SomeProperty

So that is it possible to have something like this:

```
public string PrintFullName(???? object)
{
    //????
}
```

I put `????` for the input `Type`, because I don't know what the proper input `Type` is.

I want the result of the PrintFullName to be:

> Foo.SomeProperty

I don't necessarily look for *run*-time solutions. Any *compile*-time workaround will also help.

Comment: You can't access `Foo.SomeProperty` since SomeProperty is an instance member of `Foo`. You can olny write `instanceOfFoo.SomeProperty`. You only may use reflexion on the class type to get members definitions.

Comment: @OlivierRogier `Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo.SomeProperty))` is now a valid C# expression for C# 6

Comment: It's still not clear - assuming that you got this to work, *why* would `PrintFullName` return "Foo.SomeProperty"? What is the connection between the two?

Comment: Maybe you meant something like `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo).Name + "." + nameof(Foo.SomeProperty));` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it prints the result but is it possible to wrap it inside something that inputs the property alone?

Comment: @yekanchi Cool! Very usefull. Thanks. This works: `Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo) + "." + nameof(String.SomeProperty));`

Answer (score 2):

Sure this is possible, using expression trees.

A full explanation on this [site](https://daveaglick.com/posts/using-expression-trees-to-get-class-and-member-names) (all credits to Dave Glick).

It comes down to this:

```
public void UseNames(string className, string memberName)
{
    // Your code to use the class & membername go here
}

public void UseNames<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
    {
        // The property access might be getting converted to object to match the func
        // If so, get the operand and see if that's a member expression
        member = (expression.Body as UnaryExpression)?.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
    if (member == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Action must be a member expression.");
    }

    // Pass the names on to the string-based UseNames method
    UseNames(typeof(T).Name, member.Member.Name);
}

public void UseNames<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
{
    ConstantExpression constant = expression.Body as ConstantExpression;
    if (constant == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a constant expression.");
    }
    UseNames(typeof(T).Name, constant.Value.ToString());
}
```

Use it like this:

```
UseNames<Foo>(x => nameof(x.Bar));
UseNames<Foo>(x => nameof(x.Baz));
```

Comment: Why the nameof? Your code seems to work with `UseNames<Foo>(x => x.Bar)`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and maybe faster) solution, without expression trees (which use reflection):

```
public string PrintFullName<T>(String memberName)
{
    return $"{typeof(T).Name}.{memberName}";
}
```

Usage:

```
PrintFullName<SomeType>(nameof(SomeType.SomeProperty));
// Compiled to: PrintFullName<SomeType>("SomeProperty");
```

`nameof()` is a compile-time construct, so no need to build a slightly advanced solution that performs evaluation at runtime more than required.